# Laravel 5.8 . Почему меняется порядок ключей, при сохранении данных в столбец типа JSON

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.8

указан этот порядок ключей при создании юзера:

```
$user->emailNotifications()->create([
            'settings' =>
                [
                    "orders"        => [
                        "paid"    => false,
                        "snipped" => false,
                    ],
                    "store_actions" => [
                        "added"               => false,
                        "deleted"             => false,
                        "transferred_license" => false,
                    ],
                    "billing"       => [
                        "changed_cycle"  => false,
                        "failed_payment" => false,
                    ],
                    "products"      => [
                        "deactivated" => false,
                    ],
                ],
        ]);
```

сохраняется в базе в другом порядке:

```
"orders": {
  "paid": true,
  "snipped": true
},
"billing": {
  "changed_cycle": false,
  "failed_payment": false
},
"products": {
  "deactivated": false
},
"store_actions": {
  "added": false,
  "deleted": false,
  "transferred_license": false
}
```

Comment: Тип данных JSON хранится в формализованном виде (с целью оптимизации обработки) - т.е. он разбирается на запчасти при сохранении и воссоздаётся при получении. При этом сохранения порядка элементов, само собой, не гарантируется. [JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) *JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements.*

Comment: есть ли возможность указать строгое сохранение?

Comment: Если "порядок имеет значение" - озаботьтесь дополнением данных полем требуемого порядка. Либо храните данные в формате сырого текста.

Comment: спасибо за помощь.